# How can I return some InsettableShape Protocol in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a function which returns **some InsettableShape** like this:

```
func test(value: Int) -> some InsettableShape {
    
    if (value == 0) {
        return Circle()
    }
    else if (value == 1) {
        return Capsule()
    }
    else {
        return Rectangle()
    }
    
}
```

Xcode give an error of:

> Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types

because there is a missing ShapeBuilder or InsettableShapeBuilder wrapper, I cannot make this code work, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I believe this a duplicate of the linked question. If you think there's more to your question, ping me and we can talk about it. The short version is that `some` indicates that the return type is opaque (not known to the caller), but it's still some *specific* type. All three legs must return the same type. This is in contrast to "any" (i.e. AnyView) which means that the type is only known at runtime. Generally you should avoid AnyView, however. See the linked answer for the ViewBuilder property wrapper which allows you to do what you're looking for.

Comment: Shape is a View in SwiftUI. Is that the source of your confusion with why these are the same question? Or do you have a different question about it?

Comment: @RobNapier, it is really not related to the linked question, because provided problem does not relate to ViewBuilder (or View at all). `InsettableShape` is a specific extension of `Shape` protocol and both do not have built-in builders, and in general as I see we mignt not want to work/convert with it as/to `View`.

Comment: @RobNapier: I got confused from your last link, you mean it is generally bad idea using ViewBuilder wrapper when we are returning some View? Since we got no ShapeBuilder even for Shape that would be even bad idea?

Comment: @RobNapier: I must return InsettableShape because I am going modify it with strokeBorder later.

Comment: @Asperi Thanks for the clarification. Reopened. (Or maybe you already did it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the task is to convert all those different value-types to one single, so we need a non-generic type wrapper confirming to `InsettableShape` protocol.

Here is a simplified demo of possible approach. Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

[image: demo]

```
struct Demo_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        test(value: 0)
            .strokeBorder(Color.red, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 50.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
    }
}

func test(value: Int) -> some InsettableShape {
    if (value == 0) {
        return MyInsettableShape { Circle().trim(from: 0, to: 0.5).path(in: $0) }
    }
    else if (value == 1) {
        return MyInsettableShape { Capsule().path(in: $0) }
    }
    else {
        return MyInsettableShape { Rectangle().path(in: $0) }
    }
}

// Shape independent wrapper - possible, because any shape
// can provide a path for specified region rectangle
struct MyInsettableShape: InsettableShape {
    
    private let base: (CGRect) -> Path
    private let inset: CGFloat
    
    init(base: @escaping (CGRect) -> Path, inset: CGFloat = 0) {
        self.base = base
        self.inset = inset
    }
    
    func inset(by amount: CGFloat) -> Self {
        .init(base: base, inset: amount)
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        base(rect.inset(by: .init(top: inset, left: inset, bottom: inset, right: inset)))
    }
}
```

Comment: That is working, thanks. Let my know if i follow your code in correct way, MyInsettableShape job is basically given CGRect to already defined Shape again?! I mean the Circle is already defined, so you are accessing it's path again to given current CGRect for it right?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with @Asperi answer was when you overlap the same shape in a ZStack for fill and strockBorder, they wont match. StrockBorder inset the shape while fill does not do that.

Found this repo and it works perfect:

https://github.com/ohitsdaniel/ShapeBuilder